# ¿Como se puede copiar lo que hay en una caja de texto al portapapeles? / Python tkinter

Tags: python

Tengo una duda, la cual es si se puede copiar lo que hay en la caja de texto  al porta-papeles, y como hacer para que esa caja de texto solo permita escribir números.

```
from tkinter import *


main=Tk()
main.geometry("300x60")


caja1= Entry(main,)
caja1.place(x=20,y=20, height=20, width=200)

copiar= Button(main, text="Copiar")
copiar.place(x=230, y= 19)





main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
from tkinter import *


main=Tk()
main.geometry("300x60")

def validar_entrada(ent):
    return ent.isdigit()

validador = main.register(validar_entrada)

caja1= Entry(main, validate="key", validatecommand=(validador, '%S'))
caja1.place(x=20,y=20, height=20, width=200)

def copiar_al_portapapeles():
    main.clipboard_clear()
    main.clipboard_append(caja1.get())

copiar = Button(main, text="Copiar",command=copiar_al_portapapeles)
copiar.place(x=230, y=19)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Vaya, muchas gracias de verdad.