# ¿Cómo comparo números por posición en python?

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo en python tengo una duda, quiero hacer que un programa ejecute las siguientes instrucciones:

Para este método necesitas tener 2 cadenas diferentes por ejemplo:

4594196140816125
4594196140123118

Lo siguiente que debe hacer es separar los 6 primeros números de las dos cadenas como se muestra a continuación:

[459419] | **[6140816125]**

[459419] | **[6140123118]**

Luego lo que utilizaremos será la segunda parte que se separo de las dos cadenas:

**[6140816125]** y **[6140123118]**

Después, tiene que comprobar SIMILITUDES entre estos dos grupos:
Si tienen el mismo número, se quedan iguales, si no, se reemplazan por una X, es decir:

**[6 1 4 0 8 1 6 1 2 5]**

**[6 1 4 0 1 2 3 1 1 8]**

[0 1 4 0 X X X 1 X X]

**Que daría así = [0140xxx1xx]**

Por último, juntar los 6 primeros numeros con la segunda fila  y quedaría así:
**4594190140xxx1xx**  tiene que quedar horizontalmente y todo pegado.

Yo lo hice pero con una lista, y pues como no se puede modificar un carácter en cierta posición de una cadena de caracteres, toco separar posición por posición y guardarlas en una variable, para luego con un ***if*** compararlas una por una.
los caracteres deben de ser de 16 digitos.

```
cc1 = 4594196140123118
cc2 = 4594196140816125
   

cc1 = str(cc1)
cc2= str(cc2)
x = "x"
cc1_6 = cc1[0:6]
resultado = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

cc1_6 = cc1[6]
cc2_6 = cc2[6]

cc1_7 = cc1[7]
cc2_7 = cc2[7]

cc1_8 = cc1[8]
cc2_8 = cc2[8]

cc1_8 = cc1[8]
cc2_8 = cc2[8]

cc1_9 = cc1[9]
cc2_9 = cc2[9]

cc1_10 = cc1[10]
cc2_10 = cc2[10]

cc1_11 = cc1[11]
cc2_11 = cc2[11]

cc1_12 = cc1[12]
cc2_12 = cc2[12]

cc1_13 = cc1[13]
cc2_13 = cc2[13]

cc1_14 = cc1[14]
cc2_14 = cc2[14]

cc1_15 = cc1[15]
cc2_15 = cc2[15]


if cc1_6 == cc2_6:
       resultado[0] = "x"
       if cc1_7 == cc2_7:
              resultado[1] = "x"
       if cc1_8 == cc2_8:
              resultado[2] = "x"
       if cc1_9 == cc2_9:
              resultado[3] = "x"
       if cc1_10 == cc2_10:
              resultado[4] = "x"
       if cc1_11 == cc2_11:
              resultado[5] = "x"
       if cc1_12 == cc2_12:
              resultado[6] = "x"
       if cc1_13 == cc2_13:
              resultado[7] = "x"
       if cc1_14 == cc2_14:
              resultado[8] = "x"
       if cc1_15 == cc2_15:
              resultado[9] = "x"
   
   


print(resultado)
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta tu explicación, el resultado final debería de ser 4594196140xxx1xx no 4594190140xxx1xx. Además, deberías especificar si las cadenas tienen la misma cantidad de caracteres, para evitar especulaciones a la hora de darte una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, no me di de cuenta de ese pequeño error, ¿alguna idea de como programarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def metodo(c1, c2):
    #Tomar las segundas partes de las cadenas (A partir de la sexta posición hasta la última)

    temp_c1 = c1[6:len(c1)]
    temp_c2 = c2[6:len(c2)]

    #Iniciar la respuesta con los 6 primeros números de la primera cadena (asumiendo que son los mismos de la segunda)

    c3 = c1[0:6]

    #Comprobar SIMILITUDES entre las segundas partes de las cadenas (asumiendo que tengan la misma cantidad de caracteres)

    for i in range(len(temp_c1)):
        #Si tienen el mismo número, se quedan iguales
        if temp_c1[i] == temp_c2[i]:
            c3 += temp_c1[i]
        #Si no tienen el mismo número, se reemplazan por una 'x'
        else:
            c3 += 'x'

    #Se retorna la cadena que contiene la respuesta
    return c3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no solo quería resolverlo si no también entender lo que sucede en el código.

Comment: Puse algunos comentarios por si tienes alguna duda con lo que sucede en el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, ¿Puedes ayudarme con esta? :  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383876/como-se-puede-copiar-lo-que-hay-en-una-caja-de-texto-al-portapapeles-python

Comment: Acá te puse la respuesta a esa otra pregunta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384098/165037]